# issues with Euler 23

Tags: c++11

I've started solving Euler's problems and there is an error in Euler 23 that DOES bother me.
What's the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
long long res=0;
for (int answer=1;answer<=28123;answer++){
bool tri=false;
if (answer%6==0 || answer%20==0) continue;
for (int i=12;i<=answer;i++){
  if (abs(answer-i)%20==0) tri=true;break;
}
if (!tri) res+=answer;
 }
 cout << res << endl;
 return 0;
 }
```

The logic behind my program is : every abundant number is either divisible by 20 or 6 so I see if I can writ a number with a number divisible by 6 and a number divisible by 20.At the top of code :

```
if (answer%6==0 || answer%20==0) continue;
```

I use continue if there was a number divisible by 20 or 6 I use continue.
What's the problem?
Is it because of my solution?

Comment: Please indent the code so that it is readable

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: please add problem statement to your question

Answer (score 1):

The intent of the line

```
if (abs(answer-i)%20==0) tri=true;break;
```

is not correctly expressed in code. It is equivalent to:

```
if (abs(answer-i)%20==0)
{
   tri=true;
}
break;
```

I suspect that is not what you meant. It needs to be:

```
if (abs(answer-i)%20==0)
{
   tri=true;
   break;
}
```